# itemprop="image" on element not <img>?

Tags: html, image, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I have a product page that uses Microdata. At the moment the `itemprop="image"` attribute is specified on the first thumbnail from my thumbnail gallery.  What I'd like to do is specify it for the high-res image I have.

The trouble is, that's not actually displayed on the page, it's loaded via JavaScript using a lighbox.  I know I can do something like:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="/img/high-res.jp" style="display:none" />
```

and the image won't show and it's tagged as the product image.  But, of course the image is still download.

**Any way I can specify `itemprop="image"` on an image but not actually download the image?**

I tried changing `<img>` to `<span>` but the [testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) didn't recognise it.

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't recognise it"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the link element would be useful here - it's not displayed in the rendered HTML, but it is available in the HTML source and therefore available to JavaScript:

```
<link itemprop="image" href="/img/high-res.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. Worth a go, I tried, but unfortunately the testing tool didn't recognise it :-(

Comment: Correction!  I hadn't updated src= to href= , doing that worked.  Thanks.